# Call a function from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**Can I call a function that is not defined from a Stored Procedure ?**

Consider we have a Stored Procedure that looks like that :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp__getClients]
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    Select Id,Name,Status , 
           (CASE WHEN Status = 3 then run_date_calc(FromDate , ToDate) else '' 
            end) as DateRangeDesc
    From ClientsTbl

...
END
GO
```

I want to add another property to the `Select` like that :

```
(CASE WHEN Status = 3 then run_date_calc(FromDate , ToDate) else '' end)
```

We want to create a function inside the SP called `run_date_calc` that 
will get two dates and return a string with its range description 
looks like :

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime, @year int, @month int, @d int
set @d1 = '2009-09-24'
set @d2 = '2012-04-23'

set @year = datediff(year, @d1, @d2) - 1
set @month = datediff(month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1), @d2) 
if dateadd(month, @month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1)) > @d2 set @month = @month - 1

set @d = datediff(day, dateadd(month, @month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1)), @d2)
print cast(@year as nvarchar) + ' year(s) ' + cast(@month as nvarchar) + ' month(s) and ' + cast(@d as nvarchar) + ' day(s)'
```

Is it possible to make an "inside function" and use it inside the SP , without creating it in the DB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "create" or define a function inside an SP, no. You'll have to create it on the/a database and then reference the object you created.

If, for some *odd* reason you don't want the object to remain, you could `CREATE` it in TempDB, use it, and then `DROP` it (but this would mean the SP cannot be run by two users simultaneously, as the object would already exist).

Just create it permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in the database like this...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.run_date_calc
(
    @d1 datetime
,   @d2 datetime
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @year int, @month int, @d int;

    SET @year = datediff(year, @d1, @d2) - 1
    SET @month = datediff(month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1), @d2) 

    IF dateadd(month, @month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1)) > @d2 set @month = @month - 1

    set @d = datediff(day, dateadd(month, @month, dateadd(year, @year, @d1)), @d2)

    RETURN (  cast(@year  as varchar(10)) + ' year(s) ' 
            + cast(@month as varchar(10)) + ' month(s) and ' 
            + cast(@d     as varchar(10)) + ' day(s)'
            )

END
GO
```

And then simply call if from your proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp__getClients]
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    Select Id,Name,Status , 
           (CASE WHEN Status = 3 then dbo.run_date_calc(FromDate , ToDate) else '' 
            end) as DateRangeDesc
    From ClientsTbl

...
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks , but you're not answering my question.
I've already done that , I'm looking for a way to do it inline without defining another function.

Answer (score 1):

As you were informed, you can't define a function inside an SP.
Besides, your function is incorrect.
Look at my solution:

```
declare @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime, @year int, @month int, @d int
set @d1 = '2009-09-24'
set @d2 = '2012-04-23'


SET @year = NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)

IF @year IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD(year, @year, @d1) > @d2
    SET @year = NULLIF(@year - 1, 0)

SET @month = NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(@year, 0), @d1), @d2), 0)

IF DATEADD(month, ISNULL(@month, 0), DATEADD(year, ISNULL(@year, 0), @d1)) > @d2 
    set @month = NULLIF(@month - 1, 0)

set @d = DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(month, ISNULL(@month, 0), DATEADD(year, ISNULL(@year, 0), @d1)), @d2)

SELECT ISNULL(cast(@year as nvarchar) + ' year(s) ', '') + ISNULL(cast(@month as nvarchar) + ' month(s) and ', '') + cast(@d as nvarchar) + ' day(s)'
```

Instead of using a function you could use `CASE` statement, but in my opinion, it looks terrible:

```
SELECT 
    --Years
    ISNULL(cast(
        CASE WHEN   DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END 
    AS VARCHAR) + ' year(s) ', '')
    --Months
    + ISNULL(cast(

        CASE WHEN DATEADD(month, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN   DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2), 0), 0), DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1)) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN  DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN  DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2), 0)
            END
        AS VARCHAR) + ' month(s) ', '')
    --Days 
     + cast(DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(month, ISNULL(CASE WHEN DATEADD(month, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN   DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2), 0), 0), DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1)) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN  DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE NULLIF(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN  DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END, 0), @d1), @d2), 0)
            END, 0), DATEADD(year, ISNULL(CASE WHEN DATEADD(year, ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0), 0), @d1) > @d2 
            THEN NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2) - 1, 0)
            ELSE  NULLIF(DATEDIFF(year, @d1, @d2), 0)
            END , 0), @d1)), @d2) as nvarchar) + ' day(s)'
```

Comment: You're right , eventually I've decided to create a function for calculating the dates range.Simple ,fast and readable.
Thanks everyone!